# Resolver definitivamente problemas com caracteres estranhos no Java

Tags: java

Tive um problema e resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 nomedoarquivo.java
```

Como posso já deixar configurado esse comando para todos os arquivos?

Answer (score 4):

O ideal é que você use uma ferramenta para compilar seus programas.

Pode ser uma IDE como Eclipse ou Netbeans, onde então você configura o projeto como `UTF-8` e ainda pode definir parâmetros adicionais do compilador, mas isso depende de qual IDE você usa e qual versão.

Preferencialmente uma ferramenta de *build* como Maven ou o Gradle ajuda a definir o projeto independente da IDE. No Maven, você pode simplesmente [definir o *encoding*](https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning) na configuração do projeto que fica no arquivo `pom.xml`. Exemplo:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

Se você precisa mesmo usar linha de comando, pode tentar definir a variável de ambiente [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#tooloptions) contendo os parâmetros que deseja que sejam utilizados no comando `javac`. O problema desta abordagem é que você afeta todo o ambiente.

Uma solução mais simples para um pequeno projeto pessoal é criar um script (batch para Windows, bash para Linux ou qualquer um que você tiver disponível) que execute o processo de compilação automaticamente no seu projeto.

E é sempre bom lembrar que não é só na hora de compilar as classes que você pode ter problemas. De preferência, execute o comando `java` também passando o parâmetro de encoding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` através também de sua IDE ou linha de comando, como preferir.

Também lembre-se de que é recomendável passar o encoding sempre que converter bytes para Strings e vice-versa, sempre que ler ou gravar arquivos, transmitir dados pela rede, retornar dados em requisições e assim por diante.